# Qt for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, qt, ipad

In updated "App Store Review Guidelines", we can see:
we are relaxing all restrictions on the development tools  used to create iOS apps, as long as the resulting apps do not download  any code.

It's a good news for Adobe absolutely. But for Qt, does it mean that it's possible to port Qt to iPhone/iPhone, so that we need not to add cocoa-specific layer after that?

Or is there any solutions for Qt to iApps?

Any comments are appreciated.

-- Piaoger

Comment: Does QT have a multi-touch aware UI or API?

Comment: yes it does. there is also a community android port. and an official s60 port.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new port of Qt/Lighthouse to iOS. Already runs Qt Quick...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjYJdi48B8Q

Answer (score 3):

There is also guy who started the porting of Qt on iPhone a while ago: [Qt on iPhone](http://www.qt-iphone.com/Introduction.html)
Last time I checked he managed to compile QtCore.

Comment: @hotpaw2: yes, Qt has multitouch APIs

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be under "beta" for a long (long) time.

I think too that it would be faster to learn Apple API etc than trying to do some old QT code working on iPhone/iPad.

But good luck ^^

Comment: I think this is about portability. And a very beautiful API.

Comment: I agree with Ronny. It probably makes sense to use Core, Network, XML etc from Qt and put the native UI (Android, iPhone etc) on top of it until Qt Quick is properly supported.