# Is QT available for android and iphone platforms?

Tags: iphone, android, qt

Is QT available for the android and iphone platforms?

I want to develop a single code base for these two platforms - can it be done?

- If yes, what tools do I need? (a link to a tutorial would be great)
- If no, why not? (what are the obstacles, and how may they be overcome - i.e. workarounds?)

Comment: It you are looking for high-quality apps, Id steer clear of "write-once" pops. Universally, you end up with one platform being disadvantaged and under-perfected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is experimental Qt support for Android.

http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/

See this question for iPhone.
[Qt for iPhone/iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685553/qt-for-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 1):

You can publish for iOs, Android and even others from a single code base with [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net).  It's a cross platform game engine based on Qt/QML  with many useful V-Play QML game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, path finding and more. [API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the guys behind V-Play)