# How to reuse existing Qt code under Android?

Tags: android, qt

I have an application that was developed using Qt. This application currently runs on many different platforms.

Now, I am looking for ways to reuse this code under Android. I noticed that there is a Qt library for Android available. However, I haven't come across any article that discusses the migration topic.

I am wondering if there is a way to reuse or reorganize our existing code such that the same code base can be used on Android as well as other platforms.

Comment: There is a [Necessitas](http://necessitas.kde.org/) IDE which can be used for this purpose. Is that what you found?

Comment: Official support for Android (and iOS) is slated for Qt 5.2, which will soon be released, but is not yet available. I think what is currently available is Alpha release. You can look [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroid).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is QT available for android and iphone platforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148187/is-qt-available-for-android-and-iphone-platforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comile your app with qt5.1.1 for Android. Eventually it will run, but i am pretty sure you will have to redesign your UI, otherwise you get "Desktop-like" App for Android, which for example results in a horrible small scrollbar on high-res screens. Generally Android can run QtGui and QtQuick. There are also QGestureRecognizer available for grabbing native gestures. QSesor (and subclasses as QGyroscope, QOrientationSensor,....) for reading mobile typical sensors. While QtQuick eventually is a better fit, QtGui is still working fine.